# Expressing "any value" vs "all values" in math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to express the following sentence:

"A condition is true when $X$ is greater than or equal to **any value** of $X_m$, where $m$ consists of $1,2,...$." (note: where $m$ stops is not known in advance)

I've currently got that sentence expressed mathematically as,

$X \ge X_m \; ; \; m = 1,2... $

What would be the best way to prevent that math expression from being misinterpreted as as "...$X$ is greater than or equal to **all values** of $X_m$..."?

Comment: What you call "expressed mathematically" is neither a formula (expression) nor a phrase (sentence). It has neither the precision of formal language nor the accessibility of natural language, but combines the worst of two worlds.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Isn't that the point of the question?

Comment: @Théophile In a sense you are right. But OP presents this a bit like: "I've come so far but how do I proceed?", while as my comment points out this is already off the track, the "expression" is broken, and it is not a matter of proceeding but of starting over with a better idea of what the task is really about.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I was just trying to express the original sentence accurately and succinctly, which Theophile's had provided a satisfactory answer for. For application-related reasons I'm stuck with using $X$ and $X_m$; I didn't reveal what this task was really about (the full context, many more terms involved) because it would be off-topic for this SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:
$$\exists m\ge1 : X \ge X_m,$$
in other words, "There exists an $m \ge 1$ such that $X \ge X_m$."